# Remove duplicate values on x axis for chart js

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I have got an X axis and it has the months displaying. However for the month of august it is displaying twice...I am not to sure why that is. I would like to remove the duplicated Aug-2020 on the x Axis.

Here is a coding sandbox I created to show what I mean.

Comment: please post direct code and also attach the link to sandbox in future to reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve but in your `app.js` file change `maxTicksLimit: 5,` to `maxTicksLimit: 2,` and it will change to single value for **Aug**.

You have to calculate the chart before plotting.